# How do you force divs on to the same line, even if it means they get pushed beyond the edge of the browser?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a jquery slider, except instead of using a fixed-width container, I'm using the whole browser window. I've got jQuery set up to fix the margins to make sure it's centered correctly (although I just made them 500 pixels in the demo to keep it simple), but the problem is when I try to add more divs, it puts them on a second line instead of putting them beyond the edge of the browser. Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/JsPZT/

Eventually, I'll change the overflow so that they are hidden when they are beyond the edge of the browser, but for now, I just want to know that they are on the same line and not being pushed onto the second.

So my question is what should I change in the CSS to make sure the divs are always on the same line, even if it means pushing them beyond the edge of the window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a `width` to your `#track` CSS. That is your wrapper, and without a `width` on that, the items will just overflow and drop to the next line. You'll probably have to add another `div` to set the `overflow` and get everything positioned correctly.

Answer (score 6):

To get `div`s to stay on the same line when they are off of the screen, you have several options.  Here's what I can think of off the top of my head.

Make the parent container always large enough to hold the `div`s you want to float.  Theoretically, they shouldn't jump down to the next line that way, but I haven't tried it myself.

Another option is to use a combination of `display:table` and `display:table-cell` on the parent and children `div`s respectively.  You just have to make sure you are supporting the browsers you want to support.

My last idea is to set each `div` with `position:absolute`.  Then, just adjust the left attribute to `100% * x` to place the `div` off the screen to the left or right.  Depending on what you are trying to do, when they are off the viewable area you could just leave them at `left:-100% or 100%`.  The same should work for the `top` attribute if you want the `div` to be off the screen above or below the viewable area.

Comment: Thanks, `display:table` seems to be the only way to implement this simply with CSS, when the number of child divs is not known.

Answer (score 5):

Try `white-space: nowrap;`

If that doesn't work, you will probably need an inner `div` with a width that's the sum of all contained `div`s.

Comment: `white-space: no-wrap;` on the container div works in my situation.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;` worked for me. Can't find any reference to `no-wrap`.

Comment: @steel: I checked with http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp and you're right. Fixed my answer.

Comment: Note: The `white-space: nowrap` solution will only work if used on the parent element and requires that the child elements are inline. For `div` children, that means they must be either marked with `display: inline-block` or `float`ed